# Automatically filling a form and submitting it doesn't get the parameters to the server

Tags: php, javascript, forms, dom

I have a form that is filled automatically by a JS

My Form is:

```
<form id="doSubmit" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="usr" />
    <input type="password" id="pwd" />
</form>
```

My JS is:

```
document.forms["doSubmit"].elements["usr"].value = usr;
document.forms["doSubmit"].elements["pwd"].value = psw;
document.forms["doSubmit"].action = location.pathname + "user";
document.forms["doSubmit"].submit();
```

Now on the next page which is PHP, when I try to use the I get this error `Undefined index` and when I type `print_r($_POST)` I get `Array()`

Any idea how I can post the form data on the next page?

Comment: because the question doesn't make sense... what does 'post the data on the next page' mean? I _think_ based on answer+comments he means how does he _access_ the posted data.

Comment: @tobyodavies – Fair enough; I made up the actual question from reading the answer and comments and changed the title. I have to admit that my first thought was he was intermingling JS and PHP; @sikas – please bare in mind that we have to understand your question; try to formulate it as accurately as possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `input` elements need to have a `name` attribute:

```
<form id="doSubmit" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="usr" name="usr" />
    <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" />
</form>
```

After you've done this, you should be able to see the `usr` and `pwd` keys in the `$_POST` array in your receiving PHP script. (The keys will be the HTML `name` attribute and the value will be the corresponding `value` HTML attribute.)

So, say your form ended up looking like this:

```
<form id="doSubmit" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="usr" name="usr" value="someuser"/>
    <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" value="somepassword"/>
</form>
```

Your `$_POST` array would look like this:

```
Array (
  'usr' => 'someuser',
  'pwd' => 'somepassword'
)
```

[#### jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/QJP2A/)

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: This didn`t work with me, the $_POST is still empty

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: didn`t work even after setting name for each element!!

Comment: @sikas That makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @sikas Use Firebug to inspect your page without submitting the form that the JS is actually setting the attributes on the elements.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: I used the alert() function in JS to display the values and everything is set!!

Comment: And there's no result on the PHP end?

Comment: after submitting the form, I get and empty $_POST array!! tried on localhost and on a remote server!

Comment: Enable network monitoring in Firebug and inspect the HTTP headers sent to the PHP script, make sure that the POST array is there...

Comment: OK that is weird!! I have tried it on jsFiddle and the form action is the page on the remote server and it worked!!

Comment: @sikas – I suspect there's something else wrong on your page, as you can't post to both your local and remote server (though it could be some server configuration setting is wrong, if you installed both of them).

Comment: There is something strange now, I made the form on submit to reload the page and post the parameters and I got the values from $_POST!! and for the server installation, I have installed the localserver, yet the remote server is a free host. PLUS, I used the HTML/PHP before and was able to send data from HTML form to PHP page.

Comment: ok here is the funny part, I GOT IT DONE!! all that was missing was a '/' yeah a SLASH!

Comment: document.forms["doSubmit"].action = "../ajax/user"; is replaced with document.forms["doSubmit"].action = "../ajax/user/"; a / in the end of the action did the job.

Comment: I guess we shouldn`t under estimate the slashes anymore :D